# Pattern matching questions

Tags: pattern-recognition

I saw the below questions and was curious regarding the logic behind the answer. I will be grateful is some one could help me

[image]

So the question is given the patter, identify the next one

Comment: By looking at the directions of the arrows and their heights, I'd say E :)

Comment: Denying a relation between the even and odd elements of the sequence leads to D as a sensible choice. The change of orientation of the arrows indicates that one of D and E should be the answer.

Comment: Are you sure this has something to do with maths, and isn't some cop-out such as "how to dance the Timewarp"?

Comment: As @DouglasS.Stones mentioned at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217888/what-is-the-next-picture-in-this-sequence, this question seems to be from https://europa.eu/epso/application/passport/quiz.cfm?lang=EN&comp_id=1&quizid=10&f_sub=+OK+

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's last image

1. A -> B = 90 degree
2. B -> C = 180 degree
3. C -> D = 270 degree
4. D -> E = 360 degree
5. E -> new one = 450 degree

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the answer was D

As every other one has to be opposites and the middle denotes the direction of movement of the line.

For example, 1 and 3 are opposite, were 2 points left resulting in 3 being in the left 3rd.

Following that logic, the answer has to be opposite of 4 (pointing left) and the arrow has to move down, however, the arrow is already at the boundary meaning it returns to the top seen in the previous arrows.